# How to get maximum value among N counters in constant time?

Tags: performance, algorithm, language-agnostic

We have `N` integer counters, initially showing 0. Operations:

`int getMax()` - returns the highest value shown by counters.
`void increment(int i)` - increments value of counter `i`.
`void zero()` - set zero value for all the counters. Alternative name was `flood()`, maybe this name will be helpful to you.

Present implementation of these operations and underlying data structure, knowing that we want these operations to be as fast as possible.

---

It was my interview question. There is a small chance that I stated something a little wrong, because of my lack of memory, but I tried my best. Maybe it is similar to some well-known problem? (I hope.)

As far as I remember, all of the operations could be done in O(1)... And one of the operations was "lazy" (maybe `increment`)... i.e. in a moment of call it was doing nothing, but later when the user asked for value with `getMax()` - it worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with simply an array of size N, where each element consists of 2 numbers - the current value, and a version (say a timestamp, for example). And you also need a global last reset (zero'd) version and a global max value.

To increment:

- If that element's version is less than the global, simply set it's value to 1. Otherwise increment it.
- If it's greater than the global max, set the global max to its value.
- Set its version appropriately (to the current time).

To get the maximum:

- Simply return the global max.

To reset:

- Simply set the global last reset version (to the current time) and also set the global max value to 0.

All operations: O(1).

Comment: This has an O(n) startup cost to initialize the timestamps.  It is actually possible to change even this cost to O(1) using a more complicated [approach](http://research.swtch.com/sparse).  (I believe CPython uses this trick for its sets)

Comment: @Dukeling Great, thanks! That's exactly it. From where did you know about that?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk I'm not 100% sure to be honest. I may have remembered it (or something similar) from some time ago, or just figured it out now. The O(1) reset-all-counters definitely points to having some sort of versioning - from there it was fairly easy to figure out.

Comment: @Dukeling: can you explain why you need a timestamp and global last reset verson?

Comment: @eagertoLearn Think "Did we last change this value before or after the last reset?". With timestamps, this is easy, simply compare both timestamps. Without timestamps, this would be a difficult question to answer, unless we update every value during reset, which would cause it to take O(n) instead of O(1).

Comment: @Dukeling: I still do not understand if we really need timestamp for the operations that is in question. `getMax()` will return the `global max`, `increment(int i)` will increment at a counter specified at array index, and for `setZero()`, initialize a new Array of counters..all these operations are O(n). may be I am missing something?

Comment: @eagertoLearn "initialize a new Array of counters" takes O(n), but we can have `setZero` instead take O(1) with timestamps using the algorithm described in my post (note that my `setZero` doesn't actually involve setting any of the counters to zero - we only set them to 0 during an increment, if we see that there was a `setZero` recently by looking at the versions).